# Excel data doesn't update after data injection from an access db

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, export

Description of the situation:

I have a access DB where I export data with the following command to an excel:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet
```

The export works and the data is exported into an existing excel file into the right columns (hence the use of the upper command). What doesn't work however is the calculations of formula's used in the other fields (the fields using the data of the updated fields).

When you select a one of those fields with formula's and you just push enter, it calculates the right values with the fields that were updated by the access DB. So my guess is that the update of the fields with the formula's doesn't occur because the injection of data doesn't happen when the excel sheet is opened in excel. (so no recalculation of the fields is done with the update data)

ex:

```
Field 1 | field 2 | field 3(=Sum(Field1,Field2)
```

- Field 1 and 2 are updated via Access through the DoCmd-command.
- Field 3 should be updated with the calculation of the new values.

Any ideas on how I can force an update to these fields? (Field3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the calculation mode of the workbook. Is it set to "manual"? Go File > Options > Formulas > and under Calculation options make sure that "Automatic" is selected.

If that does not work, select all cells in the worksheet and hit F9 to re-calculate the file.

Another possibility is that the values are imported as text instead of numbers and the formulas are in text cells, too. Make sure the cells have a format other than "Text", like "General", for example.

To force re-calculation if F9 does not work, select the cells with formulas, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find/Replace dialog. In the `Find What` field enter a = sign and in the `Replace with` field enter a = sign. Then hit the button <kbd>Replace All</kbd>. This will replace all = signs in the selected cells and will force all formulas to recalculate.

If that does not help, please post a data sample that shows the behaviour.

Comment: I checked the settings, this is Ok, the select-all F9 doesn't work apparently, don't know why... . I checked the format, it's all on "General".

Comment: I @Bulki, I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: the replace-trick did the job :) sometimes the simplest solutions is indeed the best, thx!